# npm global install does not add packages to PATH on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

When I run `npm install -g <package>` it installs the packages in my user/AppData/Roaming/npm/npm_modules/ folder. This sub-folder is not in my PATH so if I try to run the package without explicitly calling the entire path the call fails with a `'<package>' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm using win8.1 and I found that the nodejs installer didn't add the path to global node modules to the system PATH. Just add `%AppData%\npm;` to the **user variable**(since %AppData% dir is depending on user) `PATH` to fix it.

You will need to log out then log back in for the change to your PATH variable to take effect.

```
SET PATH=%AppData%\npm;%PATH%
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. I did not have to log out and login though. I only restarted my command prompt which I would do anyway in order for the new `PATH` to load.

Comment: what is meant by "user variable"? the current user PATH?

Comment: @G.G windows environment variable has two kinds, global variable & user variable. when I say "user variable", it means, not the "global variable".

Answer (score 2):

You have to run this line `SET PATH=pathtonodejs;%PATH%` (where `pathtonodejs` is where you installed nodejs) once the installation for nodejs is complete and it should work.

Comment: I had done that, but it turned out I had a separate issue. I'd been following old tutorials for using Express.js. The old tutorials assumed Express would be in my path after installing it globally, but as of Express v4.0 there's a separate Express module you have to install in order to get it in your path

Answer (score 0):

It turned the problem was a change in behavior of the module I was using.

I'd been following old tutorials for using Express.js. The old tutorials assumed Express would be in my path after installing it globally, but as of Express v4.0 there's a separate Express module you have to install in order to get it in your path

Comment: this obvious is not the best answer here. please mark the answer with the highest vote count as the best answer.

Comment: @tlindell, fair enough. Done

Comment: awesome! It was just confusing at first :-D Thanks for doing that!