# LoopBack installation through npm not working on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, loopbackjs

I need to install Loopback.io in order to complete a project. You would think this would be simple enough according to the [documentation](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/).

However it simply does not work. Here is the output of `npm install`:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Arctic empire test>npm install -g loopback-cli
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\lb -> C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node
_modules\loopback-cli\bin\loopback-cli.js
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- loopback-cli@1.0.1
```

After this the lb command and get the good old:

> 'lb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have double checked all of the folders involved and everything is in place as expected. My version of node is 4.2.3 and npm is 4.1.2

Am I missing something here? Perhaps I have to mess around with the environment variables? (I've tried and it didn't get me anywhere)

Comment: definitely a path problem, likely unrelated to loopback-cli

Comment: What can I do to fix that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860262/npm-global-install-does-not-add-packages-to-path-on-windows-8-1

Comment: Definitely incompetence from my part. Worked perfectly once I fixed that. My focus was on something else.