# In leaflet: leafdoc command not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm

I want to use leafdoc to generate documents. I installed leafdoc globally with command `npm install -g leafdoc` to which some packages gets updated. But when using leafdoc command, the message appears that `leafdoc: command not found`. It would be appreciated if anybody has suggestions to this problem. For reference, here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: After running `npm install -f leafdoc`, where are your leafdoc files located?

Comment: leafdoc folder is created in node_modules

Comment: In which `node_modules` directory? Relative to where you run `npm install`, or somewhere global?

Comment: It is global, so the path is C:\Users\iga\node_modules\leafdoc

Comment: And do you have `C:\Users\iga\node_modules\.bin` in your `$PATH`? Do check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860262/npm-global-install-does-not-add-packages-to-path-on-windows-8-1

Comment: yes, I do. I am giving the command on the same path. For the reference:        /node_modules/.bin
$ leafdoc -t node_modules/leafdoc/templates/basic -o documentation.html src/leafdoc.js
/c/Users/iga/AppData/Roaming/npm/leafdoc: line 12: js: command not found

Comment: Can you *please* include all your commands, and all error messages in your original question, properly formatted?

Comment: There is a link of commands added in the question.

Comment: You'll need to debug that, in order to know which file is failing at line 12. Note that leafdoc's `cli.js` contains a `#!/usr/bin/env js` shebang, but that's at line 1, not at line 12.