# npm ERR! syscall spawn git

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, thirdweb

I have a problem
When I install thirdweb-dev/react
i get this

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ELZAHBIA\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-05-08T16_00_11_597Z-debug-0.log)
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccD9N.png]

Comment: Try some of the options listed in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990647/npm-install-errors-with-error-enoent-chmod

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the GIT installed on your device and accessible globally. Try to type `git --version` in the CMD. If it returned that the command is not recognized and GIT is already installed, then you need to add it to the PATH environment variable and make sure to try the command using a new CMD session.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was solved after updating the Github version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was related to not having the node packages of npm on my PATH. This solved the problem for me: [npm global install does not add packages to PATH on Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860262/npm-global-install-does-not-add-packages-to-path-on-windows-8-1)