# How to fix dependency conflict in JavaScript project template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, dependencies

I am working with a the [Airframe React template](https://github.com/0wczar/airframe-react) and the steps are pretty straightforward: Unzip and run `npm install` from the project directory. The problem is that I get the following error when I run `npm install`:

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: airframe-dashboard@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint@6.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"^6.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0" from eslint-config-airbnb@17.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb
npm ERR!   dev eslint-config-airbnb@"^17.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\leord\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\leord\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-15T05_07_36_689Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried using `--legacy-peer-deps`, or changing the entry `"devDependencies.eslint"` to `"*"` and to `"^5.3.0"` in the `package.json` file, but now it runs with the following error:

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\leord\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-15T05_11_22_330Z-debug-0.log
```

I also tried reinstalling Node and npm. What I find weird is that I haven't changed anything in the project and I can't run it.

I have tried it from both Windows 11 and WSL2. My IDE is WebStorm and everything is up to date.

The complete (original) `package.json` file has the following dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "airframe-dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Seed project for flexible light React/Bootstrap 4 dashboards.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npm run start:dev",
    "build:dev": "node ./build/cli-tools.js --clear dist --create dist && webpack --config ./build/webpack.config.client.dev.js",
    "build:prod": "node ./build/cli-tools.js --clear dist --create dist && webpack --config ./build/webpack.config.client.prod.js",
    "start:dev": "node ./build/cli-tools.js --clear dist --create dist && webpack-dev-server --config ./build/webpack.config.client.dev.js",
    "start:prod": "node ./build/cli-tools.js --clear dist --create dist && webpack-dev-server --config ./build/webpack.config.client.prod.js"
  },
  "author": "Webkom",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-universal-import": "^4.0.0",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^5.0.2",
    "commander": "^2.20.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0",
    "extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "file-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.33.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "@owczar/dashboard-style--airframe": "^0.1.13",
    "ag-grid-community": "^21.0.1",
    "ag-grid-react": "^21.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "holderjs": "^2.9.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "query-string": "^6.7.0",
    "rc-slider": "^8.6.13",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^11.0.4",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.22.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^3.1.4",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-editor": "^1.2.4",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-filter": "^1.1.9",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.0.6",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit": "^2.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^4.0.0-alpha.9",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dropzone": "^10.1.5",
    "react-grid-layout": "^0.16.6",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.11.0",
    "react-image-crop": "^8.0.2",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.3",
    "react-responsive": "^7.0.0",
    "react-router": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
    "react-toastify": "^5.2.1",
    "react-toggle": "^4.0.2",
    "react-universal-component": "^4.0.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "recharts": "^1.6.2",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.8.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-flush-chunks": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

How can I resolve the dependency conflict?

UPDATE:

Turns out I did not have Git installed. After installing it, trying `npm install` in the project's root folder gives me the following error:

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/Marak/faker.js.git
npm ERR! Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\leord\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-15T07_03_08_129Z-debug-0.log
```

Why do I need access to that git repo?

Answer (score -1):

Try using --force.

What is ur node/npm version?

Comment: This gave me the same `ENOENT` error.
Node is v16.15.1 and npm is v.8.11.0

Comment: I find some simmilar issues here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72163471/npm-err-syscall-spawn-git
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990647/npm-install-errors-with-error-enoent-chmod

Check it out

Comment: So turns out I did not have Git installed as I thought, but installing it didn't fix the problem. It gives me a permissions error from GitHub. I updated the question.